# how do woocommerce store shipping method rate or cost

Tags: woocommerce

Please let me know the file name or location of file where woocommerce stores the shipping method id name cost and tax status.
     woocommerce stores data in wp_options table but i am currently unable to find the files through which it is doing this 
   thanks any help will highly appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Folder in all default woocommerce shipping method class is available in wordpress.

wordpress->wp-content->plugins->woocommerce->includes->shipping

Let me know if any queries regarding the same.